# Git - How to revert a rebase that has been pushed to the remote branch (not origin)

Tags: git, git-rebase

I was working on my local branch doing some changes and when I finished I pushed everything to the remote brach. Before merging the branch with develop I thought I should do a rebase cos the other guys had merged a lot of their code there. When I did the rebase and resolved some conflicts I pushed to the remote branch. Unfortunately the way I resolved the  conflicts was wrong so now I need to go back before the rebase happened and also update the remote branch to the new state.

**What I tried**

1. Reset the head

   git reset --hard HEAD@{x} //where x is the head just before the rebase

This works and reverts the changes on my local branch but then I don't know what to make the remote branch update to that since it doesn't create a new commit that can be pushed to the remote.

Comment: use the '-f' flag with your push command.

Comment: You can use `git reflog` to find the hash of the commit before the bad rebase and `git reset --hard <hash>`. Push the result using -force.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should not rewrite the history of remote repositories because if

1. You push something broken
2. Somebody pulls
3. You force-push a different history

not only would you have the issue of having to fix the mess but everybody else who pulled the changes. So unless you can be sure that nobody pulled it, *don't do a force-push*.

Instead you should revert the commit using either

```
>> git revert HEAD@{y}   # where HEAD@{y} is the faulty commit
```

if only one commit was messy, in case of a merge.

In case of a rebase that transplatend several commits onto the master branch you need to do

```
>> git revert --no-commit HEAD
>> git revert --no-commit HEAD~1
>> git revert --no-commit HEAD~2
   ...
>> git revert --no-commit HEAD@{x}
>> git commit -m "Sorry folks for the big mess I made"
```

Where all the `HEAD~y` are the commits in between `HEAD@{x}` and `HEAD`.

This will effectively undo all affected commits in a single big commit.

Comment: Thanks for that, it worked like a charm!Plus, you were right I shouldn't force a pull.

Answer (score 4):

**Dont panic! just follow these steps in terminal**

```
git reflog
```

or

```
git log -g
```

This will show previous commits in terminal like

[image]

here commits are named as HEAD@{0}, HEAD@{1} etc. if you want to revert lastest changes than in attached pic HEAD@{5}, but it varies according to your commits

```
git revert HEAD@{5}
```

Its done. Now you see all files as before commits

Comment: This adds more "revert" commits